# Use globally installed webdriver with Protractor

Tags: angular, webdriver, protractor, continuous-integration

Currently we have the following command in our `package.json`:

`"postinstall": "webdriver-manager update"`

This is required by Protractor, but takes valuable time when running in TeamCity. Is there way to use globally installed webdrivers?

Answer (score 1):

you could use Gulp, then run everything through jenkins like this:

```
 "scripts": {
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "postinstall": "webdriver-manager update",
    "instGlobal": "npm install -g protractor gulp",
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "gulp test --suite release",
    "start": "gulp test --suite release"
  },
```

Then run

```
npm test
```